# Unity uploading player data text file to server, need some guide format

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, unitywebrequest

I need some guide in data format/syntax with php.

I have a simple form in my app, so user should fill the form and submit, Am successfully uploading my text file to my server, but need some good format.

Here is my code

```
[Header("Input Fields")]
public InputField userName;
public InputField mobileNo;
public InputField coinsToRedeem;
[Header("Data Strings")]
public string usernameText;
public string mobileNoText ;
public string coinsText;
public void GetSetData()
{
    usernameText = userName.text;
    mobileNoText = mobileNo.text;
    coinsText = coinsToRedeem.text;
    StartCoroutine(UpLoadUserData());
}
IEnumerator UpLoadUserData()
{ 
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("name", usernameText);
    form.AddField("data", mobileNoText +","+ coinsText);
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://myserver/UserData.php", form);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();
    if (www.isNetworkError)
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    else
        Debug.Log("Uploaded");
}
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php    
    if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['data'])){
        file_put_contents($_POST['name'].".txt", $_POST['data']);      
        echo "uploaded.";
    }else{
        echo "invalid file uploaded.";
    }  
?>
```

So now the data text file is uploading, and in the text i got the data like this format
"Mobile Number, Number of coins"

But i need below format
"Mobile Number
number of coins"
So, how can i write like this? Or how to add more fields?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form.AddField("data", mobileNoText +","+ coinsText);`

this is where you format your data as "Mobile Number, Number of coins"

if you change it to something like

`form.AddField("data", mobileNoText + coinsText);`

it will write Mobile Number number of coins.

Comment: Ya I know that what am done, but I need the coins will below line. How can I write this?

Comment: You can try it : `form.AddField("data", mobileNoText +"\r\n"+ coinsText);` If it doesnt work use `form.AddField("data", mobileNoText +"<br/>"+ coinsText);` instead.

Comment: Then please vote my answer as accepted dude. I need some reputation! @SimpleArcadeGamers